# Retrofit 2 how to get Array from JSON

Tags: android, retrofit

I want  get array object from JSON.
My scheme:

```
 {
   "ID":"48213",
   "TIMESTAMP_X":"23.10.2015 23:45:52",
   "TIMESTAMP_X_UNIX":"1445633152",
   "PHOTOALBUM":[
                  "20906",
                  "20907",
                  "20908",
                  "20909",
                  "20923",
                  "20924"
                ],
   "CITY_BIND":false,
  "SECTION_NAME":null
}
```

How i can get array PHOTOALBUM use Retrofit?

I try:

```
*
*
private List<String> PHOTOALBUM = new ArrayList<String>();


public List<String> getPHOTOALBUM() {
      return PHOTOALBUM;
}
*
*
```

But it's don't work.

Comment: what you mean by *But it's don't work.* ?

Comment: List<item> result = response.body(); result=null, but request successful. Code 200.

Comment: could you post more code ? What version of retrofit are you using ?

Comment: Retrofit 2.  Anover request without  array  it's works

Comment: can you share how did you parse the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a data model class for the returned JSON object, retrofit could easily return an instance of this model class :

http://kdubblabs.com/java/retrofit-by-square/retrofit-return-custom-object/

This way, you could easily extract your PHOTOALBUM array attribute by calling the returned instance's getPHOTOALBUM() method.

Gson converters are widely used : https://github.com/google/gson (very easy to integrate with retrofit to automatically serialize/deserialize your JSON objects.